# Laravel 9, Undefined variable $users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, crud, laravel-9

Please help me, I'm new to Laravel. I'm trying to view data from my table but it shows this error. I already tried different methods but all without success and I use Laravel 9.

And sorry if this problem got anwsered a lot in the past, I didnt find any solution that worked for me im sitting on this problem now for 2 days (I feel kinda stupid).

**All error messages**.

Undefined variable $users

Row: 11 in **usercrud.blade.php**

@foreach ($users as $user)

\resources\views\includes\users\usercrud.blade.php: 11

\resources\views\includes\users\usercrud.blade
.php: 11 **require**

Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions: 11
**handleError**

\resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php:8 **require**

**app -> http -> controller -> UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('id')->paginate(10); 
        return view('includes.users.usercrud', compact('users'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('includes.users.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
           
        ]);

       
        User::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('includes.users.usercrud')
            ->with('success', 'User created successfully.');
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('includes.users.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
           
        ]);

        
        $user->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('includes.users.usercrud')
            ->with('success', 'User updated successfully.');
    }

    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
       
        $user->delete();

        return redirect()->route('includes.users.usercrud')
            ->with('success', 'User deleted successfully.');
    }
}
```

**views -> includes -> users -> usercrud.blade.php**

```
<h1>User List</h1>
<a href="{{ route('includes.users.create') }}">Create New User</a>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('includes.users.edit', $user->id) }}">Edit</a>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('includes.users.destroy', $user->id) }}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>

{{ $users->links() }}
```

**views -> admin -> dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container mt-4 text-light">
        <h2>Welcome to the Admin Dashboard!</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        @include('includes.users.usercrud')
    </div>
@endsection
```

**routes -> web**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'adminDashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('includes.users.usercrud');
    Route::get('/users/create', [UserController::class, 'create'])->name('includes.users.create');
    Route::post('/users/store', [UserController::class, 'store'])->name('includes.users.store');
    Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', [UserController::class, 'edit'])->name('includes.users.edit');
    Route::put('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update'])->name('includes.users.update');
    Route::delete('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('includes.users.destroy');
});
```

I tried a lot of other methods from stackoverflow already but for some reason it wont work for me.
Also looked now at global variables but that also dont work.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: @Repox addded all the error messages now hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are including the users crud into the dashboard, but the adminDashboard controller does not pass a list of users for use when it renders the dashboard section.

Make sure wherever you want to display a list of users that you pass this list from the controller

It is not sufficient to pass the list of users from the UserController because you never access this controller when you show the dashboard from the adminDashboard controller.